# The number of ways to represent $(n^2+n)/4$ as a sum of $n/2$ distinct integers in $1,\dots,n$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, summation

For any positive integer $n$ (using integer division only), let $P(n)$ denote the number of ways in which the integer $(n^2+n)/4$ can be expressed as a sum of exactly $n /2$ distinct elements of the set $\{1,2,3,\dots, n\}$.

**What is $P(n)$ in terms of n?**  Specifically, how exponential is it? Is this less than $2^{n/2}$?

Comment: It's zero if $n$ is not a multiple of 4. Have you run any experiments? like, calculating $P(n)$ for a few small values of $n$?

Comment: In this case, I mean integer division. I care about this in cases when n is large.

Comment: If you mean integer division, you should edit your question so that it says what you mean instead of saying something different. And small values often give insight into large ones.

Comment: So one is meant to interpret \ as a symbol for integer division? Is that a standard notation?

Comment: If $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$, it is the constant term of the expression $$\prod_{i=1}^n (xz^{i}+x^{-1}z^{-i})$$ Not sure if that helps any

Comment: Here's a heuristic: (I will consider the case n a multiple of 4 for simplicity) If you take the sum of $\frac{n}{2}$ randomly chosen distinct elements from ${1,2,\cdots n}$, you will get an expected value of $\frac{n+n^2}{4},$ but you can get anywhere within a range of $\frac{n^2}{2}.$ I suspect that the expected value will be the most likely value of the sum in this range (and I suspect that this can be proven with a bit of combinatorics), which would imply that $P(n)$ would be at least $\frac{2\binom{n}{n/2}}{n^2}$, and as $\binom{n}{n/2}$ is $\Theta(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}),$ $P(n)$ should be

Comment: (continued) $\Omega(\frac{2^n}{n^{2.5}})$, in particular larger than $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ for large n.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=4k$, this is [OEIS sequence A063074](http://oeis.org/A063074). That entry and the one for [A029895](http://oeis.org/A029895) that it links to contain some suggestions for asymptotic expressions derived heuristically and/or experimentally, but no closed form or proof for an asymptotic expression seems to be known.